# Why 404 error is returning, while getting right url, in spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, http-status-code-404

i've have started lerning spring and have created simple spring mvc app.
this is my config and controller:

SpringCongig:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("exhibition")
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public SpringConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }
}
```

SpringServletInitializer:

```java
public class SpringServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {SpringConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }
}
```

Controller:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/halls")
public class HallController {
    @GetMapping()
    public String index(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>halls</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>
    Hello world!
</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

But when i folow "/halls", i always get 404 error. But earlier when i use the same configs all was good. idk what happend. Server setting was the same and ide too. I'm using tomcat 9.0.65.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a '/' at the end of the request url

Comment: it didn't help)

Answer (score 0):

Try listing all registered request mappings in the log at application startup.